# TextCtrl not changing to multiline

Tags: python, wxpython

Edit: now it looks like this
[image]

I want to set dimensions to TextCtrl containing long text and achieve [image: result]

However, my text stays single-lined
[image: current]

```
text_font = wx.Font(10, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)

self.movie_description_lbl = wx.StaticText(pnl, label="",  size=(50, 300), pos=(280,30), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE)
self.movie_description_lbl.SetFont(text_font)
test_lbl = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per incept'

self.movie_description_lbl.SetLabel(test_lbl)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the label a TextCtrl (you've used StaticText which is a label) and set the style to read-only and multi-line. You can change the background colour etc. to suit

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Title = 'Multi-line Label'

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        lbl_multi = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(300, 300), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
        lbl_multi.SetValue('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per incept')
        sizer.Add(lbl_multi)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app = wx.App()
    MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I went for StaticText because there was no background color and other things that I will have to work around.

I changed the code to:
```self.control = wx.TextCtrl(pnl, -1, pos=(300, 20), size=(330, 600),  style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY | wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL)
        self.control.SetBackgroundColour(pnl.GetBackgroundColour())```

Is there a way to hide the focus and the cursor when the mouse is over it to make it look more like a StaticText?

Comment: try HasFocus() , KillFocus() and SetCursor()